# How to print render Location's sub-fields?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to print render inside my node--article.tpl.php two of Locations sub-fields: the Street address and City
so that it looks like this: 16 Fleet Street, London -- without printing all other parameters (Province, Country etc)
So far I've got

```
<?php
    print 
        render($content['field_location'][0]['#street']) . ', ' . 
        render($content['field_location'][0]['#city']);
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please help?

Comment: Does `<?php print dsm($content); ?>` return an array with `['field_location']`?

Comment: I included your line in my node--article.tpl.php and it broke the site.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say you need `devel` module to so `dsm`, just so a `print_r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `devel` module installed than you check the exact contents of the array as: `dsm($content);`
Even if you don't have the devel module installed than check the contents of array as:

```
echo '<PRE>';
print_r($content);
echo '</PRE>';
```

I guess you probably have missed the language attribute - for regular non-location fields it's: `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['#street'];` and `$content['field_location'][0]['#city'];`

Comment: I entered your lines with PRE and /PRE and for Location field I found this: 
[field_location] => Array (
[und] => Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    ( [lid] => 31
[name] => 
[street] => boulevard de smet de naeyer 18
[additional] => 
[city] => Bruxelles
[province] => BRU
[postal_code] => 1090
[country] => be
[latitude] => 50.871899
[longitude] => 4.326884
[source] => 3
[is_primary] => 0
[province_name] => Brussels
[country_name] => Belgium
)
)

Comment: so here is solution for you: `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['street'];` and `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['city']`

Comment: I added <?php print render($content['field_location']['und'][0]['#street']); ?> and it brings out nothing.
On the other hand, <?php print render($content['field_location']); ?> prints ALL parameters of this field,while I only need "street" and "city".

Comment: please remove "#" from street and city, just try this: `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['street'];` and `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['city']`;

Comment: <?php print render($content['field_location']['und'][0]['street']); ?>and <?php print render($content['field_location']['und'][0]['city']); ?> don't work either.

Comment: How come it possible, can you send me a screenshot of the content you are getting on executing my code(that contains PRE thing), and as per the content you added in your first comment you should be able to get the value by `$content['field_location']['und'][0]['street'];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10789/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-drupalina)

Comment: I don't know how to send screenshots. To re-create this problem install Location module, add location field to a content type "Article" and then in node--article.tpl.php try to add specific parameters of the location field, and not the whole of the location field.