# How can I print render just location city in teaser view

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, location

Drupal 7

I am attempting to print just the city value within the location array.

I have created a content type with location and created a custom node template node--content.tpl.php. Inside of my if ($teaser) statement I have the following code:

```
hide($content['field_event_location']);
print render($content)
```

Which effectively hides the full field_event_location and renders all other content listed in the display settings of drupal 7 admin. I am attempting to render the city field with the following line:

```
print render($content['field_event_location']['und'][0]['city'])
```

I used

```
print_r($content);echo
```

to print the array with the following results:

```
[field_event_location] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [lid] => 167
                        [street] => 4501 Main Street
                        [additional] => 
                        [city] => Kansas City
                        [province] => 
                        [postal_code] => 64130
                        [country] => us
                        [source] => 3
                        [is_primary] => 0
                        [province_name] => 
                        [country_name] => United States
                        [email] => 
                        [phone] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

I did some basic de-bugging I found from this post ([How to print render Location's sub-fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87013/how-to-print-render-locations-sub-fields)), and was able to print `render($content['body'])` as well as get the full location output from `print render($content['field_event_location'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirty way is : don't user "render".

Just print it:

```
print $content['field_event_location']['und'][0]['city'];
```

Comment: I was unable to get print $content to work, however I did get a log message for this one _Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 94 of /sites/all/themes/theme-name/templates/node--content-type.tpl.php)._

Comment: Do you have the devel module installed? If yes, just send a dsm($content); to get the $content variable structure.
But, regarding your post and the print_r you posted, this should work.
And also you should check before that the variable exists of course...

Comment: Thanks @Matt, using devel, I was able to see the location values listed under **#items**, and not **und**. After making that change in the tpl file it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to grab the data from the node? Try this:

print $node->field_event_location['und'][0]['city'];

Comment: I was unable to get a different result from this